# Strip down by attributes a large set of models

Tags: php, activerecord, yii

I have a Yii controller action that can potentially return a very large set of rows that are then encoded into JSON. Since the client that I am building only needs a few columns or properties of the model, I would like to strip down the set to only return certain columns. What I have now is something like:

```
$models = MyModel::model()->findAll($criteria);
$rows = $model->attributes;
$this->_sendResponse(200, CJSON::encode($rows));
```

I feel like the place to do it would be in the second line but I am new to Yii and do not know how to do this. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

maybe you could not remove unnecessary columns, but send necessary?

```
$models = MyModel::model()->findAll($criteria);
// do foreach loop with $models ?

$dataToSend = array()
$dataToSend['id'] = $model->id;
$dataToSend['name'] = $model->name;
$dataToSend['moreparam'] = $model->moreparam;

//send data
$this->_sendResponse(200, CJSON::encode( $dataToSend ));
```

So this code is more readable and we know what are we sending. If you use removing some attributes later maybe you will forget what you are leaving.